# boost 1.68 asio not working in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-date-time, vcpkg

I just installed VS 2017 and vcpkg on my new system. I installed all of the boost libraries using the x86 static triplet, but after running very trival codes that uses boost.asio I keep get errors.
This is the code I tested with...

```
int main()
{
boost::asio::io_context ioc;

ioc.post([]() {std::cout << "hello"; });
ioc.run();

}
```

```
namespace "boost::date_time" has no member class "gregorian_calendar_base"   
Accountting C:\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows- 
static\include\boost\date_time\gregorian\greg_calendar.hpp  

... etc
```

Comment: Tested other functionalities like boost:: filesystem, does that work? I prefer installing boost from command prompt rather than vcpkg because multiple variable install options.

Comment: Your code example is missing the includes you're using...